# Error: Typing on the input field of pick for each row just duplicates whatever value was entered in the qty field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I have this field where you can enter the quantity for each row. It was working, however, when I added another input field for the pick, it will just duplicate whatever was entered in either of the fields. How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

adding into the cart items:

```
const handleAdd = (id, name, price, size, cat, color, quan = null, pick) => {
    console.log("add", id, name, price, size, cat, color, quan, pick);
    const productExist = cartItems.find(
      (item) => item.id === id && item.color === color
    );

    if (productExist) {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((item) =>
          item.id === id && item.color === color
            ? {
                ...productExist,
                quantity:
                  quan === "" || quan ? quan : +productExist.quantity + 1
              }
            : item
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCartItems([
        ...cartItems,
        { id, name, price, size, cat, color, quantity: 1, pick }
      ]);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have serval errors in your code.

1. First, you  are not setting values in correct order when calling `handleAdd` method. That's why you are facing issues you have described in your question.
2. Second, there is no property in object `item` called `prodName`, it should be just `name`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-to-cart-sampled-2-with-material-ui-table-pagination-forked-msc09x?file=/src/App.js) is working solution.

Comment: Hello,I tried it but it won't let me increase the quantity when clicking the "+" button  and I can't type in the input field pick, it just shows as 0

Comment: @PennieCorhon I added that pick label should only accept numbers, so if you type letter it will automatically assign it value 0. I leave it like that, and I fixed rest of the code. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just removed the `isNan` and just passed `pick`, I can now type in the text field for the letter.